# Updated to Xcode 7.1 (from 6.4) caused UIIMageView animation broken

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, xcode6, xcode7

I upgraded my Xcode project that has been compiling just fine in 6.4 and choose not to upgrade to Swift 2.0 (I want to get it to compile first before causing more errors).

I got hundreds of errors, most have been fixed now, but I can't figure this one out. This has been working in 6.4:

```
var imgListArray:NSMutableArray = []
self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray as [AnyObject]
```

I get the error in 7.1.1:

```
'NSMutableArray' is not implicitly convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
```

If I try the compilers suggestion I get this:

```
self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject]
```

That gives me the error:

```
Cannot assign value of type '[AnyObject]' to type '[UIImage]?'
```

Comment: Your `imgListArray` should be of type `[UIImage]` rather than `[AnyObject]` so you do not need to cast it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed your error:

```
   var imgListArray = [AnyObject]()
        self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray as! [UIImage]
```

Comment: Value of type '[UIImage]' has no member 'addObject'. If you look at my code you will see it is a mutable array so that I can add images to it.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock: The `var imgListArray = [AnyObject]()` declaration makes a mutable Swift `Array`. Swift arrays don't have `addObject` - use `append` instead.

Comment: Ah, I was declaring it as a NSMutableArray - so surprised. Anyhow - I got it to compile, but I am fixing the rest of the project to get it to fully compile to test your answer to make sure it works, if so I will accept it then.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is declare imgListArray as array of images.
Here is how to do that:

```
var imgListArray: [UIImage] = []
self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray
```

Comment: I also get an error trying to add to the mutable array.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide code and error message?

Comment: Value of type '[UIImage]' has no member 'addObject'. If you look at my code you will see it is a mutable array so that I can add images to it.

Comment: use append() instead of addObject